# Extract HDFS folder or file details

Tags: hadoop, hdfs, hiveql

To find the number of files present in a `HDFS` directory at any point of time using hive, I have created a hive external table. Can any one please help me in extracting the file details of directories present in `HDFS` as `INPUT__FILE__NAME` or `hdfs dfs -stat` is not serving my purpose and I want all the `-ls` into a `csv` file.

Answer (score 0):

Working with the output of ls is not recommended, it is not made for this. That being said this is not the normal ls so perhaps there is no alternative.

You can put its output in a file like so:

```
hadoop fs -ls /path > output.txt
```

Answer (score 0):

you can also use hdfs to find a table in all databases:

the path of hive databases is:

/apps/hive/warehouse/
so, by using hdfs :

hdfs dfs -find /apps/hive/warehouse/ -name t*

or

hadoop fs -ls /path